# Convergence interval of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{1} ^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{n} x +2}{x^{2n}+1}$$

I have no idea how to find the convergence interval.

Comment: Which is the index of summation?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{split}
|\sin^n x| &\le 1\\
\frac {\sin^n x + 2}{x^{2n} + 1} &< \frac {3}{x^{2n}}
\end{split}
$$

And by the comparison test the integral converges whenever $|x| > 1$